# ArgumentNullException Vs Contract.Requires

Tags: exception, code-contracts

The **ArgumentNullException** throws an exception if the argument that is passed to it is null. This happens at the runtime. What does **Contract.Requires** do? Is it a compile time checking or checked at runtime?

Comment: A NullArgumentException doesn't throw anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Contract.Requires` is a runtime check (the runtime checks are automatically generated at compile time - see chapters 6.2 and 7 of the [documentation](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/contracts/userdoc.pdf)). There are also certain static checks that can be performed (see chapter 6.6 of the [documentation](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/contracts/userdoc.pdf)), but `Requires` is a runtime check.

Note that there is a generic overload that'll let you specify the exception that you want thrown (eg, ArgumentNullException)